# Phonegap 3.6.3 ajax not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, cordova

I'm confused here. If I call the following from chrome console:

```
$.get('http://ipinfo.io/json').success(function(d){ console.log(d) }).error(function(d){ console.log(d) })
```

it displays the object as expected and then logs the result of my request (whether is succeeds, fails, etc...).

If i run the exact same code in the web inspector of safari connected to my app in (via the web inspector in iOS) I still is the object created, but the result is never displayed.

However if I expand the object, I can see that it has returned with a result, but never called the "success" callback. Any idea why it is ignoring the callback?

EDIT: The really weird thing is if the save the above call in a variable:

```
var c  = $.get('http://ipinfo.io/json').success(function(d){ console.log(d) }).error(function(d){ console.log(d) })
```

and then read c.responseText .. the result is right there... my "success" callback is just never fired..?

Answer (score 0):

try using this code to show your result instead `[Object object]`

```
$.get('http://ipinfo.io/json').complete(function(d) {
    JSON.stringify(d);
});
```

Comment: Well, that wouldn't help me as the error and success callbacks are never called. The problem is earlier in the pipeline (and seems to be phonegap specific, as i cannnot replicate in safari, chrome or anyother browser).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I never figured out why this was happening, but rebooting the computer and/or using another computer solved the problem. So I think the safari developer features where having some serious problems.